# How do you pass in as parameters the MuleMessage and Payload using Annotations on a Java component?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a class that I am wiring as a java component like so:

```
    <component doc:name="eduPubService">
      <method-entry-point-resolver>
          <include-entry-point method="checkAndReserve" />
          </method-entry-point-resolver>
          <spring-object bean="edusPubService"/>
    </component>
```

I'm trying to access the MuleMessage and Payload using Annotations like so:

```
public class PublicationServiceImpl implements PublicationService {
    public Object checkAndReserve(@Mule("message") MuleMessage message, @Payload String payload) throws Exception {  ..... }
```

The Payload that I'm passing in is a String.  I don't think I quite understand how these annotations work.  I assumed that they grabbed the MuleMessage and Payload from something like the EventContext, but I'm getting EntryPointNotFoundExceptions because it is looking for a method 'checkAndReserve' that takes only a String as its parameter.  How would I define a class and method that make use of the annotations above, and is called using the method name?  I don't like the idea of using Callable, as I would have to create a separate class for every custom component/transformer.  If I rely only on the method signature to resolve the payload, as the error seems to indicate is necessary, I still don't know how to get at things like session variables, the Mule Message, etc.

Comment: What do you need the `MuleMessage` for? Conceptually, a component should not have to deal with the message. Are you transforming the message? Then write a custom transformer. Or if you really need deep access to the event, write a custom message processor. Otherwise, use the `invoke` message processor and call your method with the just what it needs (payload, specific props/vars...).

Comment: I'm using the mule method to get at and set session variables within a Java component.  I think I may be abusing the Java component, though, and should probably be doing this in a custom transformer, or a custom message processor.  I think I need to do a little more reading to understand the key differences between the three approaches, and when to use what.  About the last option, `invoke`, can you give me an example or a link to any documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Can't find any doc :( Look for `<invoke` in https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/tests/integration/src/test/resources/org/mule/test/construct/flow.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make changes to the Message in the flow, like setting session variables, it's recommended to create a Custom Transformer that extends from AbstractMessageTransformer and implement the method transformMessage.

This is an example of a custom transformer:

```
package com.test;    

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class MyTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer{


    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
            throws TransformerException {
        //Add Session Variables
        message.setProperty("variable1", "value1", PropertyScope.SESSION);
        message.setProperty("variable2", 100, PropertyScope.SESSION);
        //Get Payload
        Object payload = message.getPayload();
        return message;
    }


}
```

And this is the way you can use it in the flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
      xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp"
      xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
      xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
      xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
      xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
      xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws"
      xmlns:smtps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps"
      xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
      xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
      xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps/current/mule-smtps.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
    ">



    <custom-transformer name="myTransformer" class="com.test.MyTransformer" />


    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Refactoring_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8181" >
        <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="64" />
     </http:listener-config>




     <flow name="JobExecutorProcessor" doc:name="JobExecutorProcessor">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="vm.in.test" doc:name="VM"/>

        <logger message="Calling myTransformer" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <transformer ref="myTransformer" />     

     </flow>


</mule>
```